# PyTorch Lightning fails to load the weights for the test when multiple models are training simultaneously

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I want to run a hyperparametertuning with different models simultaneously but for the last line in the following block:

```py
model = model(**params)
trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator='gpu', devices=1, precision=32, log_every_n_steps=1, max_epochs=1500, 
                            callbacks=[pl.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filename = "best", monitor="Validation                    Loss MSE", save_top_k = 3),
                                    pl.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(save_last =True),pl.callbacks.early_stopping.EarlyStopping(monitor="Validation Loss MSE", patience=50),
                                    ])
tuner = pl.tuner.Tuner(trainer)
tuner.lr_find(model,datamodule)
trainer.fit(model, datamodule)
trainer.fit(model, datamodule)
trainer.test(ckpt_path= str(os.path.abspath(__file__).rsplit('/', 1)[0]) + "/lightning_logs/version_" + str(trainer.logger.version) +"/checkpoints/best.ckpt", datamodule = datamodule)
```

I am getting the error message:

```py
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for CNN_LSTM4:
        Missing key(s) in state_dict: "init_h", "init_c", "lstm.weight_ih_l0", "lstm.weight_hh_l0", "lstm.bias_ih_l0", "lstm.bias_hh_l0", "lstm.weight_ih_l1", "lstm.weight_hh_l1", "lstm.bias_ih_l1", "lstm.bias_hh_l1", "linear_layers.3.weight", "linear_layers.3.bias", "linear_layers.3.running_mean", "linear_layers.3.running_var", "linear_layers.9.weight", "linear_layers.9.bias", "linear_layers.9.running_mean", "linear_layers.9.running_var", "linear_layers.15.weight", "linear_layers.15.bias", "linear_layers.15.running_mean", "linear_layers.15.running_var". 
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "linear_layers.20.weight", "linear_layers.20.bias", "linear_layers.20.running_mean", "linear_layers.20.running_var", "linear_layers.20.num_batches_tracked", "linear_layers.24.weight", "linear_layers.24.bias", "linear_layers.2.weight", "linear_layers.2.bias", "linear_layers.2.running_mean", "linear_layers.2.running_var", "linear_layers.2.num_batches_tracked", "linear_layers.8.weight", "linear_layers.8.bias", "linear_layers.8.running_mean", "linear_layers.8.running_var", "linear_layers.8.num_batches_tracked", "linear_layers.14.weight", "linear_layers.14.bias", "linear_layers.14.running_mean", "linear_layers.14.running_var", "linear_layers.14.num_batches_tracked". 
        size mismatch for cnn_layers.0.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1003, 1, 19, 24]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1023, 1, 21, 24]).
        size mismatch for cnn_layers.0.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1003]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1023]).
        size mismatch for cnn_layers.0.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1003]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1023]).
        size mismatch for cnn_layers.0.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1003]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1023]).
```

This error only happens when I run the same script simuntenously for different models.

I would like to succesfully load the weight for each model, so that I can run multiple trainings at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the author of the question to refactor the code because not it is not clear what the `datamodule` is and why you call `Trainer.fit` twice. Moreover, you should use just a single `ModelCheckpoint` callback.

I also suggest to give each run a different `name` to avoid conflicts that may arise when writing checkpoints to the `lightning_logs` folder.

A possible fix could be:

```py
model = model(**params)
trainer = pl.Trainer(
    output_dir=os.path.join('lightning_logs', 'some name for this experiment'),
    accelerator='gpu',
    devices=1,
    precision=32,
    log_every_n_steps=1,
    max_epochs=1500, 
    callbacks=[
        pl.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            monitor="Validation Loss MSE",
            save_top_k=3,
            save_last=True,
        ),
        pl.callbacks.early_stopping.EarlyStopping(
            monitor="Validation Loss MSE",
            patience=50,
        ),
    ]
)

tuner = pl.tuner.Tuner(trainer)
tuner.lr_find(model,datamodule)

trainer.fit(model, datamodule)

trainer.test(ckpt_path="best", datamodule=datamodule)
```